# Using hadoop with Qt

Tags: qt, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Does anybody know how to use hadoop with Qt , any tutorials for hadoop with Qt or any Qt wrapper or hadoop streaming with Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three basic interfaces to Hadoop's map/reduce:

- Java interface
- Pipes (C++ interface)
- Streaming API (any language)

So if you want to use C++ to write your m/r tasks you got two options - use streaming API or/and Pipes. Pipes is just a C++ library, so I think its no problem to link it with your Qt program. [There](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#pipes) is a manual that can help you.